# Change SQL Server Maintenance Plan Report Location?

Tags: sql-server-2008, maintenance-plan

I created some Maintenance Plans in SQL Server 2008 without using the wizard (i.e. right-click on Maintenance Plans and select New Maintenance Plan...). When created that way, there is no option to specify the location for the Maintenance Plan Action Report. It is by default placed in the Log subfolder of the Program Files folder for that instance of SQL Server. When creating Maintenance Plans using the Wizard, you can specify the location for those report files.

I can't find a way to modify the report file location after-the-fact. The edit screen doesn't give you the option of specifying the location and there doesn't appear to be a way to load an existing plan into the wizard for modification. When I view the T-SQL, I don't see any option for the report file.

Is there a way to change the location that the Maintenance Plan Action Reports go to without recreating the plans using the Wizard?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using SSMS, double click on your Maintenance Plan in the Object Explorer.  In the Object Explorer Details, click on the "Reporting and Logging" icon (typically next to the "Manage Connections" button).  In this window, you can specify the location for text file reports.

Answer (score 0):

If your maintenance plan has to appear below the "Maintenance Plans" node in SSMS, I can't help.

Otherwise...
Maintenance Plans in SQL Server 2008 are usual SSIS packages. You can use BIDS (Business Intelligence Developer Studio) and create your maintenance package. After that, you can store the package where ever you want and call it by SQL Server Agent.

Hope this helps a bit,
Flo